# Is there a version of Unix where "if" is a command in /bin?

Tags: unix

Is or was there ever a version of Unix where the shell builtin "if" was a command (like `/bin/[` and `/bin/test`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highly unlikely. `if` is not a *command*; it is part of the *sh* shell syntax, with **different parsing rules** in order to allow command lists, nested `if`'s, and so on.

For example, the following would be plain impossible if `if` were a command, since the parser would just stop at `if test -e file;` without considering the rest.

```
if test -e file; then
    echo "File exists"
else
    if touch file; then
        echo "File created"
    else
        echo "File couldn't be created"
    fi
fi
```

Or this:

```
if case $path in
   ~/trash/*)  false;;
   ~/*)        true;;
   /proc/*)    false;;
   *)          true;;
esac; then
   backup "$path"
else
   echo "skipping $path"
fi
```

Unless you wanted to resort to such things as quoting... lots of quoting. **And** it would require either reimplementing the same shell parser *inside* `if`. If you simply had it spawn a new `imaginarysh -c <argument>`, then it would be impossible to modify variables inside the command lists.

```
/bin/if "test -e file" "echo \"File exists\"" "if \"touch file\" \"echo File created\" \"echo \\\"File couldn\\\'t be created\\\"\""
```

(Aside: `if` is actually a command in the [Tcl programming language](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1042), and it works just like the example above, except with balanced `{` `}` for quoting blocks of code.)

---

But on the second thought, if `if` were a command, **it would become impossible to modify variables** inside the command lists *anyway*. Anything modified inside the `if` arguments would be impossible to reach the main process.

Finally, there is **absolutely no advantage** to implementing `if` externally. In shells, testing the condition consists of 1) running the command, and 2) checking its exit code. If `if` were external, your shell **would have to do the same anyway**, otherwise it wouldn't know if `if` succeeded or failed. (The same functionality is used in `||` and `&&` conditionals, too.)

(Aside: In early Unix prototypes, [`chdir` was an external command](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/hist.html).)